# SQL Server CE and thread safe connections should I use lock on the resource?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have implemented a SQL Server CE 4 database into a web service in C# .NET.

I have shared the database connection between the web services invocation making the connection object as static (so shared by invocations):

```
private static SqlCeConnection sqlConnection;
```

Than I have implemented different methods as the following:

```
lock (sqlConnection)
{
   SqlCeCommand cmd = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
   tryOpenConnection();

   try
   {
      cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM STAKEHOLDER";
      SqlCeDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

      while (rdr.Read())
      {
         String toAdd = "";
         toAdd = rdr.GetString(0) + "," + rdr.GetString(1);
         stakeholderList.Add(toAdd);
      }
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      stakeholderList.Add("ERROR|" + e.Message);
   }

   sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

The question is:

Is it correct to lock the `SqlCeConnection` for each call?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should work but you should use a different object for locking rather than the connection object. Somewhere in the base hierarchy, it inherits from MarshalByRefObject, which makes it an object with weak-identity. For more info check out

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182290(v=vs.100).aspx